# Working on pivots intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I am learning linear algebra using Gilbert Strangs "Intro to LA" 4th edition. On problem set for chapter 2.3 "Elimination Using Matrices" I encountered a question I can't wrap my head around(problem 5):

*Suppose a<sub>33</sub> = 7 and the third pivot is 5. If you change a<sub>33</sub> to 11, the third pivot is ____. If you change a<sub>33</sub> to ____, there is no third pivot.*

Problem 3 mentions matrix A:

```
A = [[1 1 0]
     [4 6 1]
     [-2 2 0]]
```

I am assuming problem 5 refers to that matrix.
The answer is 9 and 2 respectively. I don't understand this question at all. If a<sub>33</sub> is the coefficient matrix then a<sub>33</sub> = 7 means the third is pivot is 7, how can it be 5 at the same time. I feel like I am missing some fundamental concept there...

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit mislead by this problem as well. It does actually correspond to the matrix from problem 3. $a_{33}$ can be $7$ while the third pivot is $5$ because the elimination process alters the the bottom right value. If you substitute $7$ for the bottom right $0$ in $A$ and eliminate until there is only an upper triangular matrix, the third pivot will be $5$. You can then use the same process with $11$ and an unknown for the two parts of the question to get $9$ and $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The $k^\text{th}$ pivot, if I remember things from that book correctly, is defined as the first nonzero entry in the $k^\text{th}$ row, after row-reduction (ref form). So the pivots would only necessarily correspond to the diagonal entries if the matrix is upper-triangular (with nonzero entries on the diagonal).

Comment: I've edited the question with more details. If my assumptions are correct, I still don't understand the relationships between the third pivot and a<sub>33</sub>. Does it make more sense to you?

Comment: @NindzAI: I don't think problem 5 is referring to that matrix. I think you are supposed to assume that you have an arbitrary matrix $\begin{bmatrix} *&*&* \\ *&*&* \\ *&*& 7 \end{bmatrix}$ that you know has third pivot 5, and figure out how changing the 7 changes the pivot. (Notice that $a_{33}$ actually plays a very minor role in the row-reduction for any $3\times 3$ matrix).